# Managing Labels and their References in one TEX file that includes various TEX files

Tags: cross-referencing, winedt

I have one TEX file that utilizes various TEX files via INCLUDE command. My problem is to cite a label of one file in another file.
FOR EXAMPLE. I have created labels in all Chapt1 to Chapt4 files. Now, I want to cite a particular label of Chapt1 file in Chapt3 file, but in Chapt3 file, when I use \ref{}, it just gives me labels of Chapt3 only but not all of labels.

Is there any way to have all the labels displayed whenever I use \ref{} command.

Following is the MWE for my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate,amsmath,graphicx,setspace,bm,mathdesign,amsthm,amssymb}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\begin{document}
I have on big file that handles multiple chapter files.
\onehalfspacing
\include{Chapt1}
\include{Chapt2}
\include{Chapt3}
\include{Chapt4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as far as latex is concerned it is just one document so you can \ref any label defined in any chapter. by "display" do you mean display in some help text shown by your editor? If so it is an editor specific question and you need to say which editor you are using.

Comment: @Carlisle, I am using WINEDIT.

Comment: I have never used that editor so I can't help, but if you want a winedit user to see the question I suggest you edit the question and title to ask about winedit help texts to make it clear that you are asking about winedit help not about how latex displays the reference.

Comment: Simply set your main file as "main file" in WinEdt, that is be sure that the focus is in your main file and press Ctrl+F5.

Comment: @karlkoeller, Thanks a lot it worked for me.

Comment: @KashifAli You're welcome. I'll change my comment into an answer so to remove this question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working at a multi-document project, WinEdt offers the possibility to "set" your main file as such.

To do that, press <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> when the focus is on your main file, or press the "Set Main File" button either in the toolbar or in the Tree interface:

[image]

In this way, whichever file you are working at, WinEdt always refers to the main file.

So, when you compile the main file is compiled, when you type `\ref{}` the GDI Popup interface shows all the labels in your project and so on.